What is `acpi_pad` and how do I stop it taking up so much CPU?
The kernel thread acpi_pad is taking up the vast majority of my compute resources on my home server. Does anyone know how to fix this? I did a standard install using the following:

Hardware: Dell PowerEdge R320
CPU: Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2440 0 @ 2.40GHz
OS: Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS



acpi_pad is a system kernel module called the "ACPI Processor Aggregator Driver" and is supposed to handle high core count processor power management. At least, according to Intel.
The issue with it eating 100% CPU is unfortunately known.
To fix this long-term, disable this module:

Edit /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf and add this line:
blacklist acpi_pad

This prevents the module from loading at boot.

To fix this real-time in the interim without rebooting, do the following - note if you don't do the last line stated above, you'll have to do this every reboot:
sudo modprobe –r acpi_pad

If this doesn't work, then do the blacklist changes above, and then reboot your system.



The above is extracted from, and based on, an Intel-produced document titled "Intel Omni-Path Performance Tuning" from November 2015


You call this a "fix", but just disabling the module seems more like a stopgap. Surely that thing exists for a reason.

@marcelm you're right it does, but this is Intel's recommendation with Xeon processors, not my own.  If the issue is known even by Intel, and there's still no fix with the issue known since 2015, then there's really nothing we can do here.

@ThomasWard worked perfectly and there is a 0% change I would have found that myself - thanks!
